# Elasticsearch create join field (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have the following docs:

```js
export class CustomerServiceResultType{
  id: string;
  body:{customerRelation: string};
}

export class CustomerType{
  id: string;
  body:{name: string};
}
```

I want `CustomerServiceResultType` to have a relation to `CustomerType` with the field: `customerRelation`.

this is my mapping:

```js
await this.elasticsearchService.indices.putMapping({
  "index": "db",
  "type": "CustomerServiceResultType",
  "body" : {
      "properties": {
        "customerRelation": {
          "type": "join",
          "relations": {
            "CustomerServiceResultType": "CustomerType"
          }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

This is the error I get:

```
[Nest] 421512   - 11/21/2020, 6:40:42 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] illegal_argument_exception +96414ms
ResponseError: illegal_argument_exception
```

There are no details about this error...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your request per-se -- I think it just requires one extra option: `include_type_name: true`.

It's [`undefined` by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_indices_putmapping) in nodejs but is required in [ES 7.x](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/removal-of-types.html) on the server side. More reasoning behind this is [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/moving-from-types-to-typeless-apis-in-elasticsearch-7-0).

So this should do the trick:

```
await client.indices.putMapping({
  include_type_name: true,
  index: "db",
  type: "CustomerServiceResultType",
  body : {
      properties: {
        customerRelation: {
          type: "join",
          relations: {
            CustomerServiceResultType: "CustomerType"
          }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Typed indexes will be removed in 8.x so the best approach would actually be:

```
await client.indices.putMapping({
  index: "db",
  body : {
      properties: {
        customerRelation: {
          type: "join",
          relations: {
            CustomerServiceResultType: "CustomerType"
          }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

BTW: your typescript types don't really play a role here because ES is a JSON-only interface and while there's the deprecated `type` aspect to ES, the two concepts are very distant.