# Elasticsearch exact match query (not fuzzy)

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query over a string field:

```
const query = {
        "query": {
          "match_phrase": {
            name:  "ron"
          }
        },
        "from": 0,
        "size": 10
      };
```

these are the names I have in the database

```
1. "ron"
2. "ron martin"
3. "ron ron"
4. "ron howard"
```

the result of this query is very fuzzy, all the of the rows are returned instead of row number 1 only.
It's like it is performing "contains" instead of "equals".

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your case, all the documents are returning, because all the documents have `ron` in them.**

If you want that only the exact field should match, then you need to add `keyword` subfield to the `name` field. This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer (notice the `".keyword`" after `name` field). Try out this below query -

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "name":"ron"
}
{
    "name":"ron martin"
}
{
    "name":"ron ron"
}
{
    "name":"ron howard"
}
{
    "name": "john howard"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "name.keyword": "ron"
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "64982377",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.2039728,
        "_source": {
          "name": "ron"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Update 1:**

Based on the comments below, if you want to search for both exact match and fuzzy match (according to your requirement), then you can use [multi_match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html).

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "howard",
      "fields": [
        "name",
        "name.keyword"
      ],
      "type": "phrase"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "64982377",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 0.83740485,
        "_source": {
          "name": "ron howard"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "64982377",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "5",
        "_score": 0.83740485,
        "_source": {
          "name": "john howard"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you! Must I create a special mapping for that? can't just change the query? I have 500 GB of information... I think it would be very dangerous to do so, no?

Comment: @SexyMF have you created any explicit index mapping or you are using dynamic mapping?

Comment: You should know that sometimes i want to search by exact match, and sometimes I want to search in a fuzzy way... like in sql. thanks

Comment: @SexyMF can you please give an example for your use case where you want to search for both fuzzy and exact match ? And if you are using dynamic mapping then I believe you don't need to create any special mapping (because in the above example I have also considered dynamic mapping only)

Comment: @SexyMF If you want to search for both fuzzy and exact match the best way is to use a multi-match query. If you can give an example of your use case, I can add a working example for the same :)

Comment: "I can add a working example for the same" without a special mapping? about the fuzziness. sometimes you search for someone that you don't know his full name. only last name, so you want broad results. sometimes you know the exact full name, so you want accurate results. also in emails... thanks again

Comment: @SexyMF please go through my updated answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Should I change the mapping for that?

Comment: @SexyMF If you are using dynamic mapping then no need to change the index mapping, can you please share your present index mapping ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. this worked! if you dont mind to have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64945581/elasticsearch-create-join-field-nodejs Ill be very thankfull

Comment: @SexyMF Sure, I will try to answer your other question as well. Thank u for accepting my answer, hope you have upvoted the answer as well :)